# Is there a good way to trigger some action through Bluetooth (Low Energy)?

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, logitech

I have a device (Raspberry 3/4 with a Python3 program, using bluepy) that is triggered by the Logitech Pop button (BLE), but because I don't like it to do a round trip over the Internet, so I just scan BLE and activate if its mac address pops up. This all seems *very* hacky (BLE/bluepy even throws an error every once in a while so I have to restart BT regularly, but that's another story).

Is there a better way to implement having a BT device like the Logitech Pop being used as a trigger (without unnecessary round-trips)?

Comment: Look for MQTT protocol, and subscribe and publish like protocols, it's used for things like you want to try to make

Comment: MQTT seems a bit overkill but the right tool. MQTT(-SN) seem a bit too much effort to set up for BLE, but maybe I haven't stumbled upon the right tools for python and BLE yet. 
I noticed that if I handle the scan in bluepy better, it maybe could work as well. Still feels like a hack, but it seems to be easier to handle all kinds of bluetooth and BLE devices as buttons.

Comment: From what I understand, the MQTT stuff only really makes sense, if I can either change the data the BLE device sends (set a topic, in case of the Logitech Pop, not possible) or find out what the device sends and subscribe to it (How? Sounds like I would have to sniff out the BLE signals)

Comment: I think this might be helpful: https://github.com/bogdanoniga/ble_gateway